# Ruby: Sorting hash by key and tie-breaking on value

Tags: ruby, sorting, associative-array

Is it possible to take a `Hash` in ruby such as

```
{"aaa" => 255, "abc" => 255, "acb" => 255, "dcv" => 2300, "abe" => 1}
```

And sort it in into an `Array` like such

```
[["dcv", 2300], ["aaa", 255], ["abc" => 255], ["acb" => 255], ["abe", 1]]
```

Using the `sort_by` method? This sort should produce an array of arrays sorted first by the numerical occurrences in descending order and then on ties it should sort by the string alphabetically in ascending order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
h = {"aaa" => 255, "abc" => 255, "acb" => 255, "dcv" => 2300, "abe" => 1}
h.sort_by { |k,v| [-v,k] }
# => [["dcv", 2300], ["aaa", 255], ["abc", 255], ["acb", 255], ["abe", 1]]
```

Comment: Can't you simply use `h.sort_by { |k,v| -v }` ?

Comment: @yossarian that works by accident. It fails the tiebreak rule when the order of the hash is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving it

```
h = h.sort_by { |k,v| v }.reverse

puts h.inspect
```